# No real gains using cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to use a modified version of the RANSAC regressor algorithm, but instead of changing the sklearn's function (to avoid the problems of be using sklearn 0.24.1 and to avoid some warnings from the function), I've found an algorithm in github and was trying to cythonize it to improve speed before I can make my modifications. To my surprise the speed gain was very poor, was it because the code is full of numpy calls or did I make something wrong? The following codes are the python version, cython version (with proper modifications to avoid errors):

```
##Python version
import numpy as np
def ransac_polyfit(x,y,order, t, n=0.8,k=100,f=0.9):
    
    besterr = np.inf
    bestfit = np.array([None])
    for kk in range(k):
        maybeinliers = np.random.randint(len(x), size=int(n*len(x)))
        maybemodel = np.polyfit(x[maybeinliers], y[maybeinliers], order)
        alsoinliers = np.abs(np.polyval(maybemodel, x)-y) < t
        if sum(alsoinliers) > len(x)*f:
            bettermodel = np.polyfit(x[alsoinliers], y[alsoinliers], order)
            thiserr = np.sum(np.abs(np.polyval(bettermodel, x[alsoinliers])-y[alsoinliers]))
            if thiserr < besterr:
                bestfit = bettermodel
                besterr = thiserr
                     
    return bestfit
```

```
##Cython version
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

np.import_array()

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef ransac_polyfit(np.ndarray[np.npy_int64, ndim=1] x,
                    np.ndarray[np.npy_int64, ndim=1] y,
                    np.npy_intp order, 
                    np.npy_float32 t, 
                    np.npy_float32 n=0.8,
                    np.npy_intp k=100,
                    np.npy_float32 f=0.9):
    
    cdef np.npy_intp kk, i, ransac_control
    cdef np.npy_float64 thiserr, besterr = -1.0
    cdef np.ndarray[np.npy_int64, ndim=1] maybeinliers
    cdef np.ndarray[np.npy_bool, ndim=1] alsoinliers
    cdef np.ndarray[np.npy_float64, ndim=1] bestfit, maybemodel, bettermodel
    
    bestfit = np.zeros(1, dtype = np.float64)
    for kk in range(k):
        maybeinliers = np.random.randint(len(x), size=int(n*len(x)))
        maybemodel = np.polyfit(x[maybeinliers], y[maybeinliers], order)
        alsoinliers = np.abs(polyval(maybemodel, x)-y) < t
        if sum(alsoinliers) > len(x)*f:
            bettermodel = np.polyfit(x[alsoinliers], y[alsoinliers], order)
            thiserr = np.sum(np.abs(polyval(bettermodel, x[alsoinliers])-y[alsoinliers]))
            if (thiserr < besterr) or (besterr == -1.0):
                bestfit = bettermodel
                besterr = thiserr
    
    #Since I can't return an empty array, I had to set it as an array with a zero and the ransac_control variable will tell if the function was able or not to find a good model
    if (besterr == -1.0):
        ransac_control = 0
        return ransac_control, bestfit
    else:
        ransac_control = 1
        return ransac_control, bestfit
```

**PS: Couldn't send the image of the HTML page of the cython code because it's my first question

Comment: Rewriting in Cython doesn't necessarily mean there will be significant performance gains; the difference will likely be insignificant when most of the work is being done by C code anyway (in this case, numpy).

Comment: Numpy is already implemented with very heavily optimized C code, you would be hard-pressed to write code that outperforms it

Comment: I see on loop (over `range(100)`, and with in that `numpy` heavy code, `randint`, `polyfit`.  `cython` does best when there are lots of iterations, and action can be translated into straight forward `c` code.  `cython` has a way of generating an `annotated` html display.  Bright yellow lines are Python heavy ones that `cython` has not been able to compile.